# How to get the grandparent directory's path in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm using `dirname( $path )` to get the parent directory's path. For example:

```
$path = 'home/grandparent/parent/child.php';

$dir = dirname( $path ); // home/grandparent/parent
```

How can I get the grandparent directory's path?

For example, I need to get:

```
home/grandparent
```

**Note**, I'm coding inside child.php and need to use the path as a `string` in that file.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: Well, the parent directory is `..`: `home/grandparent/parent/..`

Comment: I need to use the path as a `string` in my code.

Comment: What about `dirname(dirname($path)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bolt on another call to `dirname`, so if

```
$path = 'home/grandparent/parent/child.php';
$dir = dirname( $path );
```

gives you

```
home/grandparent/parent
```

then

```
dirname(dirname($path));
```

gives you

```
home/grandparent
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
dirname($path.'/../');
```

Answer (score 0):

dirname() will always return parent directory path so you can:

```
dirname(dirname($path));
```

another way is to use [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

Answer (score 0):

Sample from my code:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```